# Sort CollectionView by group, where the group was created with a ValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collectionview

I have a CollectionView, cv, who's items are divided into two groups like so:

```
cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(null, new ItemGroupConverter()));
```

Without having a regular Property to toss into a SortDescription, how can I sort the CollectionView by group affiliation, as dictated by my converter? I want to do this without creating a new Property on the items within my CollectionView.

Also worth mentioning is that I prefer to stick with my current CollectionViewSource being bound to an `ObservableCollection` rather than a `ListCollectionView` because there are some notification handlers that I'm relying on with my UI.

Answer (score 1):

If your `CollectionView` is a `ListCollectionView` you can use [ListCollectionView.CustomSort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.customsort(v=vs.110).aspx) property to set an `IComparer` to do your custom sorting. You can either extend your current `ItemGroupConverter` class to implement the `IComparer` interface or make a new class that implements `IComparer` that uses an `IValueConverter` to compare the values. Assuming your `Convert` returns a string or some other IComparable:

```
public class ItemGroupConverter : IValueConverter, IComparer
{
    //... your existing implementation of Convert and ConvertBack

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return ((IComparable)Convert(x, null, null, null)).CompareTo(((IComparable)Convert(y, null, null, null)));
    }
}
```

And use it as such:

```
((ListCollectionView)cv).CustomSort = new ItemGroupConverter();
```

The other option is a Comparer that you pass an `IValueConverter` instance to use:

```
public class ConverterComparer : IComparer
{
    private readonly IValueConverter converter;

    public ConverterComparer(IValueConverter converter)
    {
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return ((IComparable)converter.Convert(x, null, null, null)).CompareTo(((IComparable)converter.Convert(y, null, null, null)));
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
((ListCollectionView)cv).CustomSort = new ConverterComparer(new ItemGroupConverter());
```

Comment: Unfortunately my `CollectionView` is not a `ListCollectionView`. I'm using an `ObservableCollection` for my `CollectionViewSource` instead because I need to hook my CollectionView's Items into my underlying ListBox's ItemSource so they can be viewed in my UI. Any workaround given this circumstance?

Comment: Are you sure? If you use `ObservableCollection` as the Source, then I believe the CollectionViewSource should use `ListCollectionView` as the `CollectionView` type. Have a look in the debugger to see what actual type your `CollectionView` is.

Comment: My mistake, you're right. With this approach, however, it seems my Compare method is never getting called, even after calling a Refresh() on my CollectionView.

Comment: maybe try setting `IsLiveSorting` to true?

Comment: Resolved that issue. I'm also using a few SortDescriptions on this same collection. Do you know if there's a way to prioritize the group sorting discussed above over all of the SortDescriptions I'm working with?

Comment: Only way I can think of is to add a SortDescriptions to the `ConverterComparer` and add the SortDescriptions to it instead of the `CollectionView` and then implement the SortDescriptions sorting in the `Compare` method of the `ConverterComparer`

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it:

Dave's answer did work. Although, I had to separate my `Converter` and `Comparer` into separate classes because I needed slightly different logic between how I differentiated between groups and how I sorted the entire collection.

I didn't figure out how to make the group ordering we worked out in my `Converter` overprioritize my `SortDescription`, so I ended up getting rid of the `SortDescription` and adding that logic into my `Comparer`.